# Сортировка массива по времени

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Возможно ли отсортировать такой массив по времени.

```php
(
    [68620] => Array (  
        [event_name] => текст 
        [event_time] => 11:30-12:30 
        [event_date] => 11 марта 
    ) 
    [68621] => Array ( 
        [event_name] => текст
        [event_time] => 12:45-13:10 
        [event_date] => 11 марта 
    ) 
    [68622] => Array ( 
        [event_name] => текст
        [event_time] => 13:15-13:45 
        [event_date] => 11 марта 
    ) 
    [68623] => Array ( 
        [event_name] => текст
        [event_time] => 10:00-12:30 
        [event_date] => 11 марта 
    )
)
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/array.sorting.php. Дальше дело техники.

Comment: uasort() позволяет использовать свою функцию для сортировки. Изучайте. Вобщем, там нужно в функции проверять два значения и вернуть true / false (больше / меньше)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = [
    68620 => [
        'event_name' => 'текст',
        'event_time' => '11:30-12:30',
        'event_date' => '11 марта',
    ],
    68621 => [
        'event_name' => 'текст',
        'event_time' => '12:45-13:10',
        'event_date' => '11 марта',
    ],
    68622 => [
        'event_name' => 'текст',
        'event_time' => '13:15-13:45',
        'event_date' => '11 марта',
    ],
    68623 => [
        'event_name' => 'текст',
        'event_time' => '10:00-12:30',
        'event_date' => '11 марта',
    ],
];

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['event_time'] == $b['event_time']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['event_time'] < $b['event_time']) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($array, 'cmp');
```